# Map array values to string keys in a if statement javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, if-statement, material-ui

I have a list that i want to display in a dropdown. The onchange in handled by

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    onFilterChange(filterName, event.target.value);
    }
 };
```

event.target.value is what is pulling the information.

My dropdown list items are listItems = ['greaterthan', 'lesserthan, 'equal'], which are string keys that are fed into event.target.value.

My issue is that i want listItems to be an array of symbols( >, <, =) instead of words. But my components only works with the word keys.

I want to create an if statement in the handler that maps the word value to the signs array.

ex.

```
const listItems = ['>','<','=']

const handleChange = (event) => {
        onFilterChange(filterName, event.target.value);
        if (event.target.value === '>') {
          // then use key value of greaterthan
        } if (event.target.value === '<') {
          // then use key value of lesserthan
        } if (event.target.value === '=') {
          // then use key value of equal
        }
      }
```

;

I'm feeding it into a select component by using

```
<Select>
{listItems.map((listItem) => <MenuItem value={listItem}>{listItem}</MenuItem>)}
</Select>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You write that `event.target.value` are values like "greaterthan", but then you say you want to map signs to words. But you already have the word. You would need the opposite?

Comment: @trincot Yes I guess so. Sorry for the confusion. I want the signs to be displayed but use the value of the words. The component only works when listItems are the words

Comment: So maybe edit the question?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create am object map to retrieve the respective ids :

```
listItems = {
  ['>']: 'greaterthan',
  ['<']: 'lesserthan',
  ['=']: 'equal'
}

const handleChange = (event) => {
        onFilterChange(filterName, event.target.value);
        if (event.target.value === listItems['>']) {
          // then use key value of greaterthan
        } if (event.target.value === listItems['<']) {
          // then use key value of lesserthan
        } if (event.target.value === listItems['=']) {
          // then use key value of equal
        }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see. But what would the return of the if statement be?

Comment: it depends, what do you want/need it to be ?  if you need the sign, you can just return the sign, if you need the id, you can just return the `listItems[sign]`.

Comment: Looks like object map isnt working for my case. I get an error saying listItems.map isnt a function. I am feeding the operands into a select component like this. {listItems.map((listItem) => <MenuItem value={listItem}>{listItem}</MenuItem>)}. I've updated my question for visuals.

Comment: Would you minde creating a jsfiddle or executable code ? The question is unclear.